# What should I check when I can't SSH into my box?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, iptables, ssh-tunneling, fail2ban

I update my :

- /etc/ssh/sshd_config, update port from 22 to 558
- /etc/fail2ban/jail.local, update port from 22 to 558
- add a new record in iptables

  `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 558 -j fail2ban-ssh`

I restarted all 3 services

As you can see, I checked if I did connectly :

```
iptables -L  --line-numbers | grep 558
cat /etc/fail2ban/jail.local | grep 558
cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config | grep 558
```

I seem to did it

[image]

I also check

`netstat -tnpl` , I see 558 there.

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:558             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21015/sshd`

Why I still can't SSH into my VM with a port 558 ?

I kept getting

[image]

Any suggestions?

---

Comment: What happens when you try to ssh into the VM? What host are you doing it from? What error message do you get?

Comment: @Kenster I added what I see. It stuck like that repeat.

Comment: You seem to have appended the iptables rule to the INPUT chain. Do you have a default "drop everything" rule in the chain before it?

Comment: Yes. Is the order of rules matters ? I think I have the drop rules before it.

Comment: Sure, only the first rule in the chain that matches will matter. That's why the "drop everything" rule is always the last one.

Answer (score 1):

The most frequent occurrence of this for me is firewall issue.

> - check outbound ports from your work station (router)
> - does your server have limited port access?
> - if you white listed your IP address check to see if your ip address has changed

Comment: try to ping the box you are looking to access [ping theUpAddress]

Comment: Please share command to `check outbound ports from your work station (router)` ?

Comment: `does your server have limited port access?` - how do I check that ?